# How to get the highlighted nodes and show them in card view?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing work on the geofencing app as I have an activity named Location history logs where I want to retrieve each data node of date (20-Mar-2019) from location logs in a separate card view and (21-Mar-2019) from location logs in a separate card view and so on to the current date how can I do it? 
 here is a link of my firebase database:

[image: Firebase JSON image]

Here is my Model class:

```
public class locationHistoryModel {

    private String Address, Key;
    private long Entered, Exited;

    public locationHistoryModel() {
    }


    public locationHistoryModel(String address_child, String key, long entered) {
        this.Address = address_child;
        Key = key;
        Entered = entered;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return this.Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.Address = address;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return Key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        Key = key;
    }

    public long getEntered() {
        return Entered;
    }

    public void setEntered(long entered) {
        Entered = entered;
    }

    public long getExited() {
        return Exited;
    }

    public void setExited(long exited) {
        Exited = exited;
    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter class:

```
public class LocationhistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationhistoryAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context mctx;
    private ArrayList<locationHistoryModel> locationHistories;

    public LocationhistoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<locationHistoryModel> locationHistoryArrayList )
    {
        mctx = context;
        locationHistories = locationHistoryArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new LocationhistoryAdapter.MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_location_historyadapter,viewGroup,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.Addresstxt.setText(locationHistories.get(i).getAddress());
        myViewHolder.EnterTimeTxt.setText(String.valueOf(locationHistories.get(i).getEntered()));
        myViewHolder.location.setText(locationHistories.get(i).getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return locationHistories.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
         TextView Addresstxt,EnterTimeTxt,location;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Addresstxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Address_child);
            EnterTimeTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Entered_timestamp);
            location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Location_child);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<locationHistoryModel> locationHistoryList;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference1;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference2;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference3;
    String date;
    String location;

    locationHistoryModel historyModel;
    LocationhistoryAdapter locationAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.childsRecycler);
        locationHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Child");
        databaseReference1 = databaseReference.child("+923452267601")
                .child("03326325635")
                .child("LocationLogs");

        databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    date = dataSnapshot1.getKey();

                    System.out.println(date + "dateee keeeeeyyyyy");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        databaseReference2 = databaseReference.child("+923452267601")
                .child("03326325635")
                .child("Locations");

        databaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    location = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    System.out.println(location + "Location Key");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        System.out.println("03326325635");
        databaseReference3 = databaseReference.child("+923452267601")
                .child("03326325635")
                .child("LocationLogs");

        databaseReference3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                historyModel = dataSnapshot.child(date).child(location).getValue(locationHistoryModel.class);
                historyModel.setKey(location);
                locationHistoryList.add(historyModel);
                System.out.println(historyModel.getAddress() + "haha" + historyModel.getKey() + "" + historyModel.getEntered());
                locationAdapter = new LocationhistoryAdapter(MainActivity.this, locationHistoryList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(locationAdapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: We can't see your database in that link, which is quite intentional. If you want to add the JSON to your question, you can add it to your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). I'd also recommend adding the code of what you already tried, as it will drastically increase the chance that someone will be able to help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for such mistake, I updated my answer can you please help me out with it?

Comment: Please don't include images in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)